# Unable to create an object of type 'MarketContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm not able to make migrations when execute

```
dotnet ef migrations add initial --verbose
```

and i got this error :

> No application service provider was found.
> Finding DbContext classes in the project...
> Found DbContext 'MarketContext'.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'MarketContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Plugins.DataStore.SQL.MarketContext]' while attempting to activate 'Plugins.DataStore.SQL.MarketContext'. at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)*

Program.cs

```cs
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
            => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        // EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
            => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
                    webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
    }
```

Startup.cs

```cs
     public class Startup
    {
        
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

            var test = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<MarketContext>(options => {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
                //options.UseSqlServer("Server =localhost; Database = Supermarket; Trusted_Connection = True;");
            });
          //  services.AddDbContext<MarketContext>();


            //Injecao de Dependencia para in Memory
            services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryInMemoryRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductsInMemoryRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ITransactionRepository, TransactionInMemoryRepository>();
            //Injecao de Dependencia para UseCases and Repositories
            services.AddTransient<IViewCategoriesUseCase,ViewCategoriesUseCase>();

            services.AddTransient<IAddCategoryUseCase, AddCategoryUseCase>();
            services.AddTransient<IEditCategoryUseCase, EditCategoryUseCase>();
            services.AddTransient<IGetCategoryByIdUseCase, GetCategoryByIdUseCase>();
            services.AddTransient<IDeleteCategoryUseCase, DeleteCategoryUseCase>();
            services.AddTransient<IViewProductsUseCase, ViewProductsUseCase>();
            services.AddTransient<IAddProductUseCase, AddProductUseCase>();
            services.AddTransient<IEditProductUseCase, EditProductUseCase>();
            services.AddTransient<IGetProductByIdUseCase, GetProductByIdUseCase>();
            services.AddTransient<IDeleteProductUseCase, DeleteProductUseCase>();
            services.AddTransient<IViewProductsByCategoryId, ViewProductsByCategoryId>();
            services.AddTransient<ISellProductUseCase, SellProductUseCase>();
            services.AddTransient<IRecordTransactionUseCase, RecordTransactionUseCase>();
            services.AddTransient<IGetTodayTransactionsUseCase, GetTodayTransactionsUseCase>();
            services.AddTransient<IGetTransactionsUseCase, GetTransactionsUseCase>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
```

MyDbContext

```cs
    public class MarketContext : DbContext
    {
        public MarketContext(DbContextOptions<MarketContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }



        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Products)
                .WithOne(p => p.Category)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId);

            //seeding some data
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(
                 new Category
                 {
                     CategoryId = 1,
                     Name = "Beverage",
                     Description = "Beverage"

                 },
                 new Category
                 {
                     CategoryId = 2,
                     Name = "Bakery",
                     Description = "Bakery"

                 },
                  new Category
                  {
                      CategoryId = 3,
                      Name = "Meate",
                      Description = "Meat"

                  }
                );

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasData(
                 new Product { ProductId = 1, CategoryId = 1, Name = "Chá Gelado", Quantity = 100, Price = 1.99 },
                new Product { ProductId = 2, CategoryId = 1, Name = "Cerveja", Quantity = 200, Price = 3.99 },
                new Product { ProductId = 3, CategoryId = 2, Name = "Pao Integral", Quantity = 200, Price = 1.50 },
                new Product { ProductId = 4, CategoryId = 2, Name = "Pao Frances", Quantity = 200, Price = 1 }
                );
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved, as you mention that the error occurs when you `add-migration` in your project

The also had this problem. It turns out I use `IGetTransactionUseCase` in both. Hence the problem occurs:

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<IGetTransactionsUseCase, IGetTransactionsUseCase>();`
```

After changing the `GetTransactionUsecase`, the problem is solved

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<IGetTransactionsUseCase, GetTransactionsUseCase>();
```

[image]

When i use this it will show the error:
[image: unable to create an object of market context]

When I change it as highlight in picture problem is solved and now my migration is complete
[image: descr]

Now you see my migration is updated successfully
[image: now you see my migration is updated successfully]

Comment: I've cleaned up your code. Good for you that you fixed the problem. But it seems the asker has not made a similar mistake (see the code). Why do you think this is an answer to this question?

Comment: this is the same question i solve it the problem is with her migration and i change it